# Same .tar different .tar.gz

Tags: gzip

I've got two .tar.gz archives here from two different origins which differ in size,

```
    -rw-r--r-- 1 aham aham 606002 Apr 28 18:26 scoop_0.7.1.orig.tar.gz
    -rw-r--r-- 1 aham aham 603839 Apr 28 18:13 scoop-0.7.1.release.tar.gz
```

When I gunzip them, the resulting tarballs are equal in size,

```
    -rw-r--r-- 1 aham aham 1024000 Apr 28 18:26 scoop_0.7.1.orig.tar
    -rw-r--r-- 1 aham aham 1024000 Apr 28 18:13 scoop-0.7.1.release.tar
```

When I re-gzip them, they again differ in other sizes,

```
    -rw-r--r-- 1 aham aham 607131 Apr 28 18:26 scoop_0.7.1.orig.tar.gz
    -rw-r--r-- 1 aham aham 604502 Apr 28 18:13 scoop-0.7.1.release.tar.gz
```

These sizes can be recreated on my machine (by again gunzip and
gzip them).

Why there are four differences in size?

Thanks in advance,
DS

Answer (score 2):

The tar balls may not be the same, although they are the same size.

Try running diff

```
diff scoop_0.7.1.orig.tar scoop-0.7.1.release.tar
```

Comment: diff says the binaries are different, but tardiff gives no result